# Python Selenium Chrome Webstore Add Extension Popup Window Problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chrome-web-store

How can I get the xpath of the window that appears when adding a extension in the chrome web store in Python Selenium.
I know there are many ways to define extension. However, I need to add a plugin from the Chrome webstore.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

I need to find the xpath of it.

[chrome webstore add extension find xpath problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REgg1.png)

I want to find the add extension xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add extension and use it with selenium and chrome driver is download the extension and load it with chrome options :

1. download the extension using this website : http://crxextractor.com/
2. Follow that code :

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
   import selenium.webdriver

   chrome_options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_extension('EditThisCookie.crx') # Add extention to chrome driver
   driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)  
   driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   # Your Code here
   ```

**That is the results**

[Click here to see Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO86T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways.
Switch to frame pop up or switch to iframe.